# tcpdump get unique IPs requesting on specific port

Tags: linux, awk, tcpdump

I want to dump unique IPs that are requesting on specific port(10301 for example). I've used command below:

```
sudo tcpdump port 10301 -nn -q ip -l | awk '{ ip = gensub(/([0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)(.*)/,"\\1","g",$3); if(!d[ip]) { print ip; d[ip]=1; fflush(stdout) } }'
```

derived from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826395/extract-unique-ips-from-live-tcpdump-capture) link.
but I'm getting this error:

```
tcpdump: syntax error
```

output without `port 10301` in the command:

```
5.22.96.170
100.116.219.232
100.123.221.113
172.17.108.177
100.120.83.187
100.123.95.221
```

Comment: Could you please output of `tcpdump` command along with your expected output in your post too?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 it prints a list of IPs line by line.

Comment: Please post a sample output of it so that we could understand your requirement clearly please, final expected output is also needed.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 question edited.

Comment: Sorry still not clear, what is the FINAL output you need to have after `awk` command?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 list of unique IPs that are requesting to my server. Just like the sample output.

Comment: try using match version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49832600/1135424

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm affraid you're mixing options and expressions of `tcpdump`, please check `man tcpdump` and try:

```
sudo tcpdump -nn -q -l ip and port 80 | awk '{ ip = gensub(/([0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)(.*)/,"\\1","g",$3); if(!d[ip]) { print ip; d[ip]=1; fflush(stdout) } }'
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks 